# How to create an MSI installer using OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, windows-installer

I already cross-compiled my program for Windows, I now have an EXE and a directory which must reside alongside that EXE in the same directory.

So I need to **create an MSI**, that places them in the appropriate place (whatever that is) and handles the uninstall too, in a way that is organic with the operative system.

There are Windows tools that do just that, but I haven't been able to find any for OS X. Is there any?

**tl;dr**:

- I am on OS X
- I cross-compiled my program for Windows
- using OS X, I need to create **an installer for Windows**, such as an MSI

I **DO NOT** need to create an installer for OS X, such as a DMG or whatever. I need to create **an installer -->FOR<-- Windows**, such as an MSI.

I just "happen" to be trying to use OS X to do it.

Using **Wine** only counts **if** that program is known to run fine with Wine.

Using a **Virtual Machine** doesn't count since it *is* using Windows, which is what I ruled out in this question.

Comment: You could always create a Virtual Machine using VirtualBox and do it that way - as a last resort - and hence this is only a comment.

Comment: @MarkSetchell you're right, I'll clarify

Answer (score 2):

It seems that msi-packager is your solution. 
"Build MSI (Windows Installer) packages on Mac and Linux."

https://www.npmjs.com/package/msi-packager

Answer (score 1):

Would it be acceptable to create an EXE-based installer instead of an MSI?

I use InstallBuilder to build installers on OS/X. InstallBuilder is a cross-platform program. There is a version that runs on OS/X and builds both EXE installers for Windows (though I have not tried that combination), as well as DMG/APPs for OS/X.

The InstallBuilder documentation mentions that it cannot build MSIs, because InstallBuilder provides functionality for which there is no equivalent in MSI.

I suggest installing InstallBuilder on your Mac, selecting "Windows" as your output format, and see what happens.

InstallBuilder is one of the better installer builders that I've worked with. It's powerful and comprehensive. Not cheap though. At $995, it's till cheaper than spinning your wheels with WiX. There is a free trial version.

Answer (score 0):

Although [WiX](https://wixtoolset.org/) is not available for OSX, there's a port of it using the wine library. You can find it in [msitools](https://wiki.gnome.org/msitools) as `wixl` which can easily installed through brew.

```
brew install msitools
```

Answer (score -3):

It sounds like you're looking for the DMG Installer specification for Mac. It's a similar function as MSI in that it is a single file containing the install components needed for an app.

Keep in mind that Mac OSX apps are very different. They are more similar to Windows directories than EXE's. They contain a sub-folder structure which includes the components of the app. If you right click on a Mac app and select "Show Package Contents" you will see a "Contents" top tier folder with everything underneath the app. Just mentioning that as it greatly impacts the lack of need for an uninstall as you simply highlight an app and click delete to remove it and all of its components. There are exceptions of course, but Mac users appreciate when dev's stick to this format.

For DMG this link may help: [Demystifying the DMG](http://newosxbook.com/DMG.html)

Comment: No, I want to create an installer for windows, not for osx.

Comment: So you're looking for a native OSX app that literally creates an MSI for Windows? I've never heard of anything that does that. Most everyone would use VMWare or Parallels to do it.

Comment: Exactly. Well, I guess I'll have to try Wine, then…